# How to export Audit Summary View in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Under 'Settings' -> 'System' -> 'Auditing' -> 'Audit Summary View' , how to export the data into an excel spreadsheet? There is no export option. Only Advanced Find that does not help me export the data I want.

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't - Microsoft hasn't exposed the export functionality for audit data - potentially because of how it is stored in the database (XML blobs)

If you have development skills, you could use the SDK to retrieve values:
[Sample: Audit Entity Data Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309735.aspx)

Otherwise if you are On Premise - you could see about creating a SSRS report.
[CRM 2011 - reports on data auditing](http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2011/11/crm-2011-reports-on-data-auditing.html)

Comment: I figured SSRS reports would be the best way to go. Thanks Jason! This really helped!

Comment: unfortunately your second link doesn't seem to work anymore. It just redirects back to the landingpage

Comment: Currently working link for "CRM 2011 - reports on data auditing" script that works for CRM 2016 as well (with a table rename) - Yay!!  https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/hardworkdays/posts/crm-2011-reports-on-data-auditing

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a commonly identified gap in the Audit Log functionality.  Here's a great solution to viewing user audit information.  Thank you Brett!  If you're looking to extend this his RDL files give you a great head start.

https://github.com/BrettRojas/CRM2011UserAuditReport

My client needed to specifically download the user access portion of the Audit Log, so I combined the two reports into one by adding the **[First(createdon)]** column to the UserLoginCount report.  Then not only do I see when the users last logged on but also get a feeling of relative usage based on number of logons in a given period.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the MSCRM Toolkit tool which is available at http://mscrmtoolkit.codeplex.com/ .  You would setup a connection to your organization and then use the Audit Export Manager tool in this tool kit to export out your Audit Summary records (you could also choose to export the detail records as well).

This tool lets you export to CSV, XML, or Excel XML formats and can filter by dates, user(s), Actions, Operations, and by entities which are enabled for auditing.  This way if you only need to see certain audit records, you can filter it before exporting.  You can even save profiles of these filter conditions, making it easy if you always need to supply an audit of "last 1 month" to auditors for compliance or for other conditions.  I've also used it to export out the user access for the last day to help in determining if a system was in use or not (to know if it was safe to restart the server or services).

I can confirm I've been able to use this in the latest CRM 2015 update 1 Online orgs without an issue to export the Audit Summary records and also works with the older CRM 2011 and CRM 2013 organizations.

I'd agree that this should just be something that is built into Microsoft CRM, but for now, this tool fits the bill to help fill the gap in functionality.